# TFS File not showing in solution, TF10187

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs

I have a branch in TFS, after making my changes I checked in and merged with my main branch. I can now see the folders and files on the server in source control. However, all of my new files and changes to certain files are not available in my solution. Any folders added are shown in the solution but not the file inside these folders. I could probably check in the main branch but wanted to build of course because nobody wants a checked-in solution that breaks the build.

Error Message:

```
Error

TF10187:Could not open document
(Path)

The system cannot find the file specified
```

Anybody have a suggestion, thanks!

Comment: Do you mean to say that the files/folders that you added exist in the Main branch but when you open the solution the files are not present? What about the changes/edits that you made? are they available?

Comment: It's got messed up. Try to get specific files, (check the get anyway overrides). Or Delete the files off your machine and get the lot again.